# DataDog Agent min_collection_interval global

Tags: datadog

I'm using V6 of the Datadog agent on Ubuntu 18.04. I'll like to change the min_collection_interval for all checks from the default 15 seconds to 30 seconds.

It's unclear from the documentation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, have you tried to add `min_collection_interval` to `init_config` section?

Seems that here you should find the answer: https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/write_agent_check/?tab=agentv6v7#collection-interval

It depends of your Agent.